# What happens when php fpm process crashes?

Tags: linux, nginx, php

For example I import a csv file for some reason the process crashes, in this case the process is restarted so I want to know the restarted process will again import the file?

Answer (score 0):

Since the process crashed, you will need to start the import again. It's possible during the import only a limited amount of data was imported, so you'll also want to check on that situation.